# Почему антоним "-фил" — "-фоб"?

Tags: словообразование, лексика, семантика

Противоположным по значению к слову *русофил* (*рус* — русский, *фил* — люблю) является *русофоб* (*рус* — русский, *фоб* — боязь, страх)? Почему любовь противопоставляется страху, а, например, не неприязни? (Ср. также: *гомофил — гомофоб, библиофил — библиофоб*.)

Comment: Впервые слышу про гомофила и библиофоба :)

Answer (score 2):

Корни древнегреческого происхождения (корневые морфемы, выступающие  в роли аффиксов, или так называемые суффиксоиды – речь идёт не о терминологии) имеют несколько синонимичных значений.
И, если выстроить синонимический ряд, то можно противопоставить синонимы к одному и к другому корню:
 "фил"- любящий, хвалящий
 "фоб"- ненавидящий, ругающий

Иноязычная морфема  -фоб-  так же, как и -фил-  имеет несколько значений, зависящих от  присоединяемой части. (Например, гемофилия – это не «любовь к крови», а заболевание, сопровождающееся  снижением свёртываемости).
Фил - от греческого слова "phileo" - любить (филология, философия, филантроп... ) – любящий, хорошо относящийся…
Фоб - от слова «φόβος» - страх, боязнь (фобия, русофоб, Фобос - спутник Марса - бога войны) – нелюбящий, непринимающий

Так почему же «любовь противопоставляется страху»?
Во – первых, корни имеют несколько значений;
во – вторых, есть понятие контекстной (или контекстуальной) антонимии;
в – третьих, иногда значение корня зависит от присоединяемой части.

Таким образом, русофобы - это те, кто ненавидит русских (Россию),
 а русофилы- это те, кто любит русский народ (Россию).

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что эти греческие корни можно противопоставить следующим образом: **иметь склонность** (любить) и **не иметь склонности** (избегать, бояться, проявлять враждебность, неприязнь,  ненавидеть).